# How to have MS Access 2003 actually prompt you before it deletes a query?

Tags: microsoft-access-2003

I was testing this today, I opened the main database window in my Access 2003 database, clicked the Queries tab in the list of objects, selected Query1 and pressed the delete key.  It just disappeared.  No "Are you sure you want to delete this query?", it was just gone.

[image: The side bar I was talking about with a query selected...and then you just press delete and it's gone!]

Is there some way of making a prompt appear in this scenario?

Comment: Better?  I had a long useless rant which must have contained the specifics of how the query was deleted, and removed that from the text.

Comment: Knowing what's ACTUALLY going on helps formulate useful answers. ;) So, to clarify, you're just clicking the query tab itself, and then hitting delete, and it closes the tab without a prompt, even if the query is un-saved?  Can you provide a screenshot, so we all know that we're talking about the same Query tab? :)

Comment: No, it was an existing query.  And I clicked it and hit delete.  Well okay so it's not a tab, it's more like a side-tab, or a side-bar?  It says objects at the top.  MS Access doesn't look like this now-ah-days.

Comment: okay...here it is...I took a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust this from the menu at:

Tools | Options... | Edit/Find | Confirm | Document deletions

(But also scripts can change it automatically when you run forms or reports.  Sometimes they can change it without you knowing it has been changed.  ... Like when they change it, then abort with an error, before they change it back to what it was.)

Comment: Ah so the code can turn it off.  That explains it.  A quick fix would be to turn it back on when it errors out.